# background-image propertie doesn't fit whole page

Tags: css, height, background-image, body-parser

Trying to use background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 0%, 100%), hsl(0, 100%, 98%)); in the whole page, however, my body and container divs aren't the whole page... Any guess why? Already tried using vh or % in body and container, no success... I'm new to CSS

CSS:

```
:root {
   --desaturated-red: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
   --soft-red: hsl(0, 93%, 68%);
   --dark-grayish-red: hsl(0, 6%, 24%);
   --gradient-one-from: hsl(0, 0%, 100%); /* Linear, 135deg */
   --gradient-one-to: hsl(0, 100%, 98%);
   --gradient-two-from: hsl(0, 80%, 86%); /* Linear, 135deg */
   --gradient-two-to: hsl(0, 74%, 74%); 
}

body {
   font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   margin: 0;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin: 0px -25px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 0%, 100%), hsl(0, 100%, 98%));
}

.logo {
   height: 33px;
   width: 158px;
   margin: 40px 80px;
}   

.model-mobile {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 65%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: -25px -30px ;
}

/* Textos */
.texts {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    max-width: 100%;
}  

.title-top {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--desaturated-red);
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 15px; 
}

.title-bottom {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: var(--dark-grayish-red);
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    max-width: 52%;
}

.description {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: 600;
   line-height: 24px;
   color: var(--desaturated-red);
   max-width: 28%;
}

.title-top, .title-bottom, .description {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* Formulário e botão */
.field-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: solid 1px hsl(0, 80%, 86%);
    border-radius: 25px ;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 410px;
    max-width: 52%;
}
  
.email-field {
   font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   margin-left: 30px;      
}

input {
   outline: none;
   width: 100%;
   font-weight: 600;
   color: var(--dark-grayish-red);
} 
  
input::placeholder {
   color: hsl(0, 80%, 86%);     
}
  
.button {
   font-size: 35px;
   font-weight: 300;
   border-radius: 25px;
   padding: 7px 35px;
}
  
.highlight {
   color: white;
   background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
}
 
.highlight:hover {
   cursor: pointer ;
   color: white;
}
  
.highlight:active {
   background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 80%, 86%));
}

.warning-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.warning-hidden {
   display: none;
}

.warning-visible {
  color: hsl(0, 74%, 74%);
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* Modal */
.modal-container {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-position {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 25px;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 260px;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: 0%;}
  to {opacity: 100%;}
}

.modal-header {
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--soft-red)
}

.thanks {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--soft-red);
} 

.modal-content {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.confirm-modal:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--soft-red)
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(60%);
  animation-name: blur-fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="novoestilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Base Apparel coming soon page</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <img class="logo" alt="logotipo" src="./images/logo.svg" width="40px" height="40px"></img>
        <img class= "model-mobile" alt="modelo" src="./images/hero-desktop.jpg"></img>
        <div class="texts">
            <p class="title-top">We're</p>
            <p class="title-bottom">coming soon</p> 
            <p class="description">
              Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store. 
              Add you email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our launch deals.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            <div id="field" class="field">
                <input class="email-field" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                <a class="button highlight">></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="warning-container">
            <p id="warning" class="warning-hidden">Please provide a valid email</p>    
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal-container">   
        <div class="modal-position">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close-modal">x</span>
            <p class="thanks">Thank you!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content">You have been subscribed successfully.</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="confirm-modal">Okay</a> 
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Already tried changing height to vh and % but then the image gets complete (what I don't want)

Answer (score -2):

The height of the container is not set properly: If the container holding the background image does not have a set height, it may not cover the entire page. You can try setting the height of the container to 100% or 100vh (viewport height) to make sure it covers the entire page.

The background image is not set to cover the container: By default, the background-image property will not cover the entire container. You can set the background-size property to cover to make sure that the background image covers the entire container.

The container has padding or margins: If your container has padding or margins, it may not be covering the entire page. You can try setting the padding and margin properties of the container to 0 to make sure that it covers the entire page.